# Searching a string and grabbing 2nd match

Tags: java, string, groovy

I started learning Groovy last week and have troubles with some code.
What I want to do:

I have a large list of names and a user input like "Hi Bob I am Sue", which is given as a string. 
I want to take this string, look into the list of names and if the string contains a greeting and two names, grab the second name and print it in an output like this:
"Hi Sue, nice to meet you".
The name "Bob" given in the example above will always be the same, so in my code I put it into a separate string, but the succeeding name can be any name (in fact, it can also be a name which is not in the name list but I don't know how to solve this yet, so that's a different matter).

What I've got so far is not much:

```
String fixedname=new String('bob')
def name=["bob","sue","peter","dr spock"] 
def greeting=["hi","hello"] 
String input= new String ('Hi bob i am sue') 

if(input.contains(fixedname) || input.contains(greeting))
```

"then look into the name list and print the name which comes after fixedname."
I don't know how to put the sentence between the quotation marks into proper code. Can someone help or give me a hint please?

Many thanks in advance and kind regards,
Kat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could possibly look at using regular expressions. Here is a quick prof of concept using your example.

```
def matcher= ('Hi bob i am dr spock'.toUpperCase() =~ /HI BOB I AM (SUE|PETER|DR SPOCK|BOB)/)
assert matcher[0][1]== 'DR SPOCK'
println("Hi ${matcher[0][1]}, nice to meet you")
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like this?

```
String fixedname = 'Bob'
List names = [ 'Bob', 'Sue', 'Peter', 'Dr Spock' ] 
List greeting = [ 'Hi', 'Hello' ] 

String input = 'Hi Bob I am Sue'

             // if the input string contains one of the greetings
def others = greeting.find { input.contains( it ) } ?
               // Split the string and return all names apart from the first one
               input.tokenize().findAll { it in names }.drop( 1 ) :
               // Otherwise others = null
               null

assert others == [ 'Sue' ]
```

Though I suspect what you are trying to do is non-trivial, and you may be better looking into some sort of natural language processing libraries